# Extract SSRS RDL files from Reporting database

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a `SSRS` reporting data backup which I have restored on my local machine.

I used a query which is returning the `RDL` raw `XML` from catalog table, but I found that server has more than 10 reports which even I am unable to view in production database.

My question is that where do I find `RDL` file, whereas Reporting Server is showing 72 `RDL` while catalog table in reporting database is showing only 10.

Comment: Can you not just grab the RDLs straight from the SSRS Server?

Comment: Are you sure you not selecting using `TOP 10`? Folders are also stored in the Catalog table, so there will be more entries than reports. However if the numbers still don't match I think you must have a different database than the report server. As you appear to have access to the report server, why not just download the definitions directly as @AlanSchofield has already mentioned?

Comment: @AlanSchofield I wish I could have but due to security reasons I am having limited access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run a backup of all your deployed reports using the following script.

- Remote to the report server using the following command line

`%systemroot%/system32/mstsc.exe`

- Then save the following procedure as a .rss file and run it with the parameter `parentFolder=""` as a zero string to save the entire folder structure with all the reports.

**Command Line:**

`rs -s http://localhost/reportserver -i D:\Scripts\Backup_Reports.rss -e Mgmt2010 -v backupFolder="D:\Scripts\BackupReports" -v parentFolder=""`

**Report Backup Procedure:**

```
Public Sub Main()
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Purpose:   Script to backup reports from a folder on ReportServer
    '            Save file as .rss extension and run using rs.exe from command line.
    ' Reference: http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/back-up-of-ssrs-reports-using-rs-utility/
    '            https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/rs-exe-utility-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017
    ' Example:   rs -s http://localhost/reportserver -i D:\Scripts\Backup_Reports.rss -e Mgmt2010 -v backupFolder="D:\Scripts\BackupReports" -v parentFolder="/IndividualReportFolderNameHere"
    '            rs -s http://localhost/reportserver -i D:\Scripts\Backup_Reports.rss -e Mgmt2010 -v backupFolder="D:\Scripts\BackupReports" -v parentFolder=""
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Try
        rs.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        Dim items As CatalogItem() = Nothing

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(parentFolder) Then
            items = rs.ListChildren("/", True)
        Else
            items = rs.ListChildren(parentFolder, False)
        End If

        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("...Backup Started...")

        For Each item As CatalogItem In items
            If item.TypeName = "Report" Then
                Console.WriteLine(item.Path)
                Dim reportPath As String = item.Path
                parentFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(item.Path) ' comment out this line to save the reports in one folder
                Dim reportDefinition As Byte() = rs.GetItemDefinition(item.Path)
                Dim rdlReport As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
                Dim Stream As New MemoryStream(reportDefinition)
                Dim backupPath As String = Path.Combine(backupFolder, Date.Now().ToString("yyyy.MM.dd") + "\" + parentFolder)

                If (Not System.IO.Directory.Exists(backupPath)) Then
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(backupPath)
                End If

                rdlReport.Load(Stream)
                rdlReport.Save(Path.Combine(backupPath, item.Name + ".rdl"))

                Console.WriteLine(item.Name + ".rdl")
            End If
        Next

        Console.WriteLine("...Backup Completed...")
        Console.WriteLine()

    Catch e As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)

    End Try

End Sub
```